# Calling javascript from ASP.NET contentplaceholder

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, d3.js

Ok I have a masterpage that has a contentplaceholder.  In the webpage I want to show a d3js graphic by calling a javascript file.  When the javascript is in the webpage it works fine, but if I copy it to a file and try and call it, it doesnt work.  I suspect this is a noob problem I have but I cant find an answer.

Javascript file;
function draw() {

```
var w = 600,
    h = 400,
    z = d3.scale.category20b(),
    i = 0;

var svg = d3.select("div.container2").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .on("mousemove", particle);
```

}

function particle() {

```
var m = d3.mouse(this);

svg.append("svg:rect")
    .attr("x", m[0] - 10)
    .attr("y", m[1] - 10)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("rx", 10)
    .attr("ry", 10)
    .style("stroke", z(++i))
    .style("stroke-opacity", 1)
    .style("opacity", 0.7)
  .transition()
    .duration(5000)
    .ease(Math.sqrt)
    .attr("x", m[0] - 100)
    .attr("y", m[1] - 100)
    .attr("height", 200)
    .attr("width", 200)
    .style("stroke-opacity", 1e-6)
    .style("opacity", 1e-6)
    .remove();
```

}

and the asp.net webpage;

```
<div class ="container2">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/testJavaScript.js">

    draw();

</script>



<!-- Core JavaScript Files -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and just so you know everything....the masterpage body;

```
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="testJava.js"></script>    
    <div class="container">
       <br />
       <br />
       <br />
       <br />
   </div>

    <div class="control">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

    <table class="auto-style1">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Copyright Martin Gardener, 2015</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

Comment: When you copy it to a file, do you copy the other javascript files, too? if not, try this first.

Comment: It's probably because the elements on the page don't exist when the script runs.  Try moving your testjava.js script tag to the end of the body.

Comment: Thanks all.  James I tried what you said and it didnt work sadly.  Burki - the other javascript files are in place sure.  I literally take the script out of the asp.net page and put it into a .js file then try and call the js file from the same place the script was.  I think Im just missing something simple from lack of experience.